# What is being not regretted in 2 Corinthians 7:10?

Tags: 2-corinthians

> **2 Corinthians 7:10**" For godly grief produces a repentance that leads to salvation without regret, whereas worldly grief produces death" (ESV).

Generally, "regret" is interpreted as meaning "not experiencing regret about the former sins".

But perhaps it means something like "... that leads to a salvation that you won't be sorry about" -- regretting that you wasted your time in that "salvation" that didn't amount to much. This meaning seems unconventional and probably unlikely, but I wonder what evidence might be for one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

That is precisely how the new, NASB20 reads the passage:

> [2 Corinthians 7:5-11 NASB20] (5) For even when we came into Macedonia our flesh had no rest, but we were afflicted on every side: conflicts on the outside, fears inside. (6) But God, who comforts the discouraged, comforted us by the arrival of Titus; (7) and not only by his arrival, but also by the comfort with which he was comforted among you, as he reported to us your longing, your mourning, your zeal for me; so that I rejoiced even more. (8) For though I caused you sorrow by my letter, I do not regret it; though I did regret it--[for] I see that that letter caused you sorrow, though only for a while-- (9) I now rejoice, not that you were made sorrowful, but that you were made sorrowful to [the point of] repentance; for you were made sorrowful according to [the will of] God, so that you might not suffer loss in anything through us. **(10) For the sorrow that is according to [the will of] God produces a repentance without regret, [leading] to salvation, but the sorrow of the world produces death.** (11) For behold what earnestness this very thing, this godly sorrow, has produced in you: what vindication [of yourselves,] what indignation, what fear, what longing, what zeal, what punishment of wrong! In everything you demonstrated yourselves to be innocent in the matter.

Apparently, Paul is saying that when one genuinely repentant it puts the spring back in your step, but without it, just a shipwreck of confidence in God and an unending sadness:

> [1 Timothy 1:19 NASB20] (19) keeping faith and a good conscience, which some have rejected and suffered shipwreck in regard to their faith.

Answer (score 1):

2 Corinthians 7:10
English Standard Version

> For godly grief produces a **repentance** that leads to **salvation** without **regret**, whereas worldly grief produces death.

The OP rightly points out the two interpretations of "regret". Some commentators connect it with salvation. Others connect it with repentance of former sins. E.g., I have no regret that I have repented of the sin of pride that I enjoyed before I was a Christian.

Can one regret salvation without regretting repentance?

That is, he does not want eternal life anymore but at the same time, he does not mind having abandoned his previous sins of pornography, drunkness, etc. In other words, he does not want to go back to his previous sinful life but he rejects his new eternal life. This scenario is unlikely.

Can one regret salvation without regretting repentance?

If a person regrets salvation, he is most likely also regretting his repentance.
Repentance and salvation are tightly linked. That's exactly what the text says: a repentance that leads to salvation.

What is being not regretted in 2 Corinthians 7:10?

It is exactly the tightly linked repentance that leads to salvation.